# How do I prevent my image from going larger than its original size but get smaller on mobile devices?

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

I want the image to never get larger and distorted but I want the edges to adjust and re-size to stay within the browsers boarders when the screen gets smaller.

EDIT:

I know about max-width but the image is smaller than the browser window.

Then the browser window is maximized i dont want the image to grow larger than its original size.

The image is about half the size of the max-width of the browser window[image]

Comment: Please show code of what you have done so far

Answer (score 0):

This will keep the image from being larger than its actual dimensions, but shrink with the container's width:

```
<img src="/yourimg.jpg" style="max-width:100%">
```

See this example and resize your browser with to see it in action:
http://jsbin.com/lonuqudaraki/1/edit

Comment: I know baout max-width but the image is smaller than the browser window.

Then the browser window is maximized i dont want the image to grow larger than its original size.

The image is about half the size of the max-width of the browser window

Comment: Here is a demonstration http://jsfiddle.net/1za8pbba/ resize the bottom right panel, you can see the image only goes as big as its original with and gets smaller when the panel is smaller

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

img {max-width:500px; margin:auto;}